# Python losing track of index location in for loop when my list has duplicate values

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I'm trying to iterate over pairs of integers in a list.  I'd like to return pairs where the sum equals some variable value.

This seems to be working just fine when the list of integers doesn't have repeat numbers.  However, once I add repeat numbers to the list the loop seems to be getting confused about where it is.  I'm guessing this based on my statements:

> print(list.index(item))
>   print(list.index(item2))

Here is my code:

```
working_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
broken_list =  [1,3,3,4,5]

def find_pairs(list, k):
  pairs_list = []
  for item in list:
    for item2 in list:
      print(list.index(item))
      print(list.index(item2))
      if list.index(item) < list.index(item2):
        sum = item + item2;
        if sum == k:
          pair = (item, item2)
          pairs_list.append(pair)
  return pairs_list  


### First parameter is the name is the list to check.
### Second parameter is the integer you're looking for each pair to sum to.
find_pairs(broken_list, 6)
```

working_list is fine.  When I run broken_list looking for pairs which sum to 6, I'm getting back (1,5) but I should also get back (3,3) and I'm not.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in my first comment. list.index() returns the first index for which the item matches the input. So when you have two identical items, i.e. "3", `list.index(3)` will return the first index at which 3 appears. So the if statement will not pass when `item == 3` and `item2 == 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `list.index(item) < list.index(item2)` to ensure that you do not double count the pairs. However, `broken_list.index(3)` returns `1` for both the first and second `3` in the list. I.e. the return value is *not* the actual index you want (unless the list only contains unique elements, like `working_list`). To get the actual index, use `enumerate`. The simplest implementation would be

```
def find_pairs(list, k):
  pairs_list = []
  for i, item in enumerate(list):
    for j, item2 in enumerate(list):
      if i < j:
        sum = item + item2
        if sum == k:
          pair = (item, item2)
          pairs_list.append(pair)
  return pairs_list
```

For small lists this is fine, but we could be more efficient by only looping over the elements we want using slicing, hence eliminating the if statement:

```
def find_pairs(list, k):
  pairs_list = []
  for i, item in enumerate(list):
    for item2 in list[i+1:]:
      sum = item + item2
      if sum == k:
        pair = (item, item2)
        pairs_list.append(pair)
  return pairs_list
```

#### Note on variable names

Finally, I have to comment on your choice of variable names: `list` and `sum` are already defined by Python, and so it's bad style to use these as variable names. Furthermore, 'items' are commonly used to refer to a key-value pair of objects, and so I would refrain from using this name for a single value as well (I guess something like 'element' is more suitable).

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm!  And thanks for the tip about the variable names too!